# Problems with simple eCart solution

Tags: php, javascript, html, e-commerce, cart

Right, I am having a nightmare.

We have been using a service called Fat Free Cart (which has so far been rather good) to build our new eCommerce website.

http://www.fatfreecart.com/

http://www.designti.me/testing/flipstick/index.php

And we have come to the point where we are looking to add postage options.

To my knowledge you cant do this with Fat Free Cart (but if you can then any help would be appreciated)

Can anybody else recommend a cart that is as simple to set up and use as FatFreeCart?

I need to be able to just copy in a line of code where I need to put a buy or Cart button and I also need to be able to get a drop down box with different postage options.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like FatFreeCart is keeping it's promises, but your application needs more features that go beyond it's scope. I like this "spartan" e-shop very much. It is great for promotion of simple items in any site.

What you could do, would be to set up a "real" e-commerce application, since you are PHP oriented, like [osCommerce](http://www.oscommerce.com/), [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) or [VirtuaMart](http://virtuemart.net/). Virtuemart is an addon for Joomla. All three offer you a full range of features and a full back-office administrator application that will allow you to make offers, define discount periods and pricing according to criteria like number of items ordered etc.

Now, you can keep your nice website and link your products straight to the appropriate items of the eshop instead of adding FatFreeCart links. This way the user will proceed to complete the purchase.

The other option would be join the E-Junkie.com team and extend FatFreeCart to do what 
you think is missing. You should be aware to keep it fat free after the add ons.

I just almost bought a Flipstick...